# Qt and OpenGL: Fragment shader won't compile when using addShaderFromSourceFile instead of addShaderFromSourceCode

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glsl, shader

I am using `QOpenGLWidget` to render some CAD meshes. I started with an example that had the shader source code written directly into the code in the following way:

1. Vertex shader

```
static const char *vertexShaderSourceCore =
    "#version 330\n"
    "in vec4 vertex;\n"
    "in vec3 normal;\n"
    "out vec3 vert;\n"
    "out vec3 vertNormal;\n"
    "uniform mat4 projMatrix;\n"
    "uniform mat4 mvMatrix;\n"
    "uniform mat3 normalMatrix;\n"
    "void main() {\n"
    "   vert = vertex.xyz;\n"
    "   vertNormal = normalMatrix * normal;\n"
    "   gl_Position = projMatrix * mvMatrix * vertex;\n"
    "}\n";
```

2. Fragment shader

```
static const char *fragmentShaderSourceCore =
    "#version 330\n"
    "in highp vec3 vert;\n"
    "in highp vec3 vertNormal;\n"
    "out highp vec4 fragColor;\n"
    "uniform highp vec3 lightPos;\n"
    "void main() {\n"
    "   highp vec3 L = normalize(lightPos - vert);\n"
    "   highp float NL = max(dot(normalize(vertNormal), L), 0.0);\n"
    "   highp vec3 color = vec3(0.39, 0.4, 0.0);\n"
    "   highp vec3 col = clamp(color * 0.2 + color * 0.8 * NL, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
    "   fragColor = vec4(col, 1.0);\n"
    "}\n";
```

I load this code into my `QOpenGLShaderProgram` with the function `addShaderFromSourceCode`. With this, everything works as expected.

Now I wanted to move the shader source code to a separate file in order to make the code cleaner. I created a .qrc file and put in the shaders in the following way:

1. Vertex Shader

```
#version 330
in vec4 vertex;
in vec3 normal;
out vec3 vert;
out vec3 vertNormal;
uniform mat4 projMatrix;
uniform mat4 mvMatrix;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
void main()
{
   vert = vertex.xyz;
   vertNormal = normalMatrix * normal;
   gl_Position = projMatrix * mvMatrix * vertex;
}
```

2. Fragment shader

```
in highp vec3 vert;
in highp vec3 vertNormal;
out highp vec4 fragColor;
uniform highp vec3 lightPos;
void main() {
   highp vec3 L = normalize(lightPos - vert);
   highp float NL = max(dot(normalize(vertNormal), L), 0.0);
   highp vec3 color = vec3(0.39, 0.4, 0.0);
   highp vec3 col = clamp(color * 0.2 + color * 0.8 * NL, 0.0, 1.0);
   fragColor = vec4(col, 1.0);
}
```

I then wanted to use `QOpenGLShaderProgram::addShaderFromSourceFile` to load the shader code from these files.
The vertex shader loads without issues, but when importing the fragment shader I get the following error message:

```
QOpenGLShader::compile(Fragment): ERROR: 4:1: ':' : syntax error syntax error


*** Problematic Fragment shader source code ***
#version 110
#ifdef GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced
#extension GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions : enable
#extension GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced : enable
#endif
#define lowp
#define mediump
#define highp
#line 1
:/globalCore.frag
***
```

which I do not understand. I don't think its a compatibility issue since I have two additional shaders if core mode is not enabled.

Can someone help me understand where this ominous "syntax error" is coming from? I don't have a colon in my shader code so I am at a loss here.

Comment: Shouldn't your fragment shader have a `#version 330` specifier?  Looks like the compiler is defaulting to GLSL 1.10.

Comment: "I don't have a colon in my shader code" -> There is one in the pre-processed code: "#extension GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions : enable".